# Change view on InfoWindowClick on Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.forms

I'm Having a problem where I need to change the View When I click on the Info Window on a google map in the renderer. I'm currently doing nothing when it gets clicked but I need to Change the View To Show More Details about the Pin. I just can't find any documentation to help with this and can't seem to figure it out.

Any help Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
googleMap.InfoWindowClicked += async (sender, e) =>{
     //put your navigation code here
     await Navigation.PushAsync(new NextView()); //replace this with your code
};
```

Comment: Thank you @javachipper I'll give it a try and let u know if i got it to work

Comment: Hi @javachipper I tried that and InfoWindowClicked doesn't seem to exist I only have a OnMapClicked which I don't Think will work for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: I’m using a google map renderer for xamarin forms and they have that one. Maybe you’re using the xamarin maps.

Comment: kindly make sure its the xamarin.forms.googlemaps library.

Comment: Hi @javachipper I checked and I am using the Xamarin.Forms.Maps I'll try and change that to the google maps one that was a major miss on my side Thanks man! :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help @ZamianvanStaden

Comment: If possible, kindly mark this as the answer as soon as you've checked so others will know. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @javachipper I've migrated my project to work with the Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps Library instead of the Xamarin.Forms.Maps and I've gotten it working perfectly thank you very much!